# Airship deep link notification is launching app with no data in the intent

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

In the Airship console, I'm sending a deep link notification with some URL, say `https://my.url`.

If I'm reading the Airship documentation correctly, the default action for a deep link notification is to fire an implicit intent containing the given URL. However, when I click on the notification, it launches into the main activity of my app and `intent.getData` returns null.

I can however read the deep link if I set up a deep link listener in code:

```
airship.setDeepLinkListener(deepLink -> {
    // deepLink is correctly received here
}
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this without setting a listener in code? I'd love to use the implicit intent approach if possible.

Note that I also tried setting various URL allow lists in `airshipconfig.properties`, hard coded to the exact deep link URL that I was testing:

```
urlAllowListScopeOpenUrl = *, https://my.url
urlAllowListScopeJavaScriptInterface = https://my.url
urlAllowList = https://my.url
```

This had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overriding onNewIntent in my launch activity and found that the deep link data was being delivered there.